# Flash Player - add trusted location without preferences panel

Tags: flash

I've written a python program that uses flash player for displaying flv videos from web. Unfortunately, user can't use it unless he add program's directory to trusted locations in Flash Player's pref panel. Is there any way to do it programatically without using that panel? It would be great if solution would work not only on Windows.

Comment: you sure you don't just need a cross domain policy file? that allows flash player to use sockets.

Comment: I think that wouldn't be enough - http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/communicate-internet-flash-content.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a file like `my_app.cfg` to

win32: `$APP_DATA$\Macromedia\Flash Player\#Security\FlashPlayerTrust`

MacOS: `$HOME$/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/#Security/FlashPlayerTrust`

the file will contain eg `c:\path\to\my\trusted\resource`

it is described here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c91.html

Answer (score 1):

Only way I know of doing this is getting a SharedObject Reader (.sol file reader)
http://www.sephiroth.it/python/solreader.php

edit: tested that SOL Reader it doesn't seem to open the settings.sol file correctly.

And editing this file

> C:\Documents and Settings{USERNAME}\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys\settings.sol

I'll be listed under `trustedPaths`

This automatically sets the trusted location settings.